# Django object function not working inside views.py

Tags: python, django

So I have an object User with the function buy(), and it works perfectly in the shell. The problem I have is when I try to use it in views.py.

```
def makeOffer(request, commodity_id):
    commodity = get_object_or_404(Commodity, pk=commodity_id)
    context = {}
    buysell = "no"
    #For some reason Try and Except must work this way....?
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(name=request.GET['user'])
        buysell = request.GET['buysell']
        shares = request.GET['shares']
        price = request.GET['price']
        if buysell == "buy": user.buy(commodity,shares,price)
        elif buysell == "sell": user.ask(commodity,shares,price)
        return HttpResponse('/trading/orders/%s/ %s %s x %s'%(commodity.id,buysell,shares,price))
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return render(request, 'trading/makeoffer.html')
```

I used HttpResponse just to debug and see if I'm getting the GET variables. Now the if and elif statement works, I tried echoing out keywords, it's the user.buy() that triggers the Try statement to run the exception and thus take me back to the form. If you're wondering what the code is, it's to simulate trading on a market.
If you want to see how it works inside the shell:

```
>>> from trading.models import*
>>> justin,jack = User.objects.all();denarii,gold = Commodity.objects.all()
>>> justin.holding(gold)
<Holding: Justin holds 0 x Gold>
>>> jack.holding(denarii)
<Holding: Jack holds 0 x Denarii>
>>> justin.holding(denarii)
<Holding: Justin holds 1600 x Denarii>
>>> jack.holding(gold)
<Holding: Jack holds 300 x Gold>
>>> justin.buy(gold, 200, 8) #This makes a buy order for 200 at 8 denarii a piece
>>> gold.offersList()
[<Offer: Buy: Gold: user: Justin --> 200 x 8>]
>>> jack.ask(gold, 300, 8) #This makes a ask order for 300 at 8 denarii a piece
>>> gold.offersList() #Leftovers of all offers
[<Offer: Sell: Gold: user: Jack --> 100 x 8>]
>>> gold.ordersList() #All orders that can get through are done
[<Order: Justin --> Jack: Gold: 200 x 8]
```

I had to painstakenly write the code by hand because my virtualbox doesn't let me copy and paste, but basically the rest of the shell prompt was just showing how the holdings, denarii and other things are all done automatically by the object.

Comment: What is the exception that's being thrown? A good rule of thumb is to use the exact exception rather than a broad catchall like you've done. I have a feeling if you remove the `try...except` and see what the real exception is, you'll probably figure out your problem.

Comment: `User` does not have a property `name` - there is a `first_name` property. Like @OozeMeister mentions, the error is being suppressed by the `try..except`

Comment: Yup it was a TypeError. Thank you very much, I can't believe I completely missed that. I was using the try and except because I don't know how else to deal with get variables.

Comment: Is there a way I can mark this as solved?

Comment: @Justin Post an answer yourself and mark it as completed: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oozemaster solved it, I was passing a str where I should've been passing an int.